# Postgres daily data dump and hydration clogs disk space?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-9.3, psql

I take a daily dump from my production environtment by doing:

```
pg_dump <database name> > dump_<date>.sql
```

then I transfer this over to staging and import the staging db by first dropping the tables:

```
drop schema public cascade;
create schema public;
```

and then doing the following:

```
psql <database name> < dump_<date>.sql
```

However it seems like the staging DB is getting unusually bigger and bigger everyday. At this point even after I drop the tables & data, there's 150 gb of space taken in the DB folder.

It feels like something like logs or metadata is clogging the folders.

What's the proper way to do this or is there a good way to clean this extra data other than deleting the DB and reinitiating it everytime.
Thanks!

Comment: did you checkout replication as suggested in my answer?

Comment: checking, thank you!

Comment: Hi there, going through some of my older answers and came across this. How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way, a much much better way.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/high-availability.html

> Database servers can work together to allow a second server to take
>   over quickly if the primary server fails (high availability), or to
>   allow several computers to serve the same data (load balancing).
>   Ideally, database servers could work together seamlessly. Web servers
>   serving static web pages can be combined quite easily by merely
>   load-balancing web requests to multiple machines. In fact, read-only
>   database servers can be combined relatively easily too. Unfortunately,
>   most database servers have a read/write mix of requests, and
>   read/write servers are much harder to combine. This is because though
>   read-only data needs to be placed on each server only once, a write to
>   any server has to be propagated to all servers so that future read
>   requests to those servers return consistent results.

Now when you read the documentation it seems very intimidating at first. However in reality all you need to do is take one dump of the entire cluster and enable WAL logging on postgresql.conf then you can copy the WAL archive files daily, weekly or monthly to another server.